# Посоветуйте обфускатор PHP

Tags: php

Посоветуйте обфускатор PHP

Comment: Быдлокодеры - лучший об**фус**катор, гарантия качества, на рынке с 1994 г. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант [PHP Obfuscator 1.5](http://kaimi.ru/2010/10/php-obfuscator-1-5/).